# How to declare unique_ptr of vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to declare a global vector of `MyClass` using `unique_ptr`. My compiler is 4.8.4.

**glo.h**

```
extern std::unique_ptr<std::vector<MyClass>> gl_vec;
```

**glo.cpp**

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<MyClass>> gl_vec;
```

And in the file where I initialize and use it for the first time in a different *.cpp file:

```
#include "glo.h"

// within function 
{
    gl_vec = std::unique_ptr<std::vector<MyClass>> ();

    cout << "gl_vec size = " << (*gl_vec).size() << endl; // crashes here
}
```

Things keep crashing when I use the pointer. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That code is not well-formed. Assignment expressions cannot occur at file scope.

Comment: What's the error? @KerrekSB I'm sure the code is well formed, but not included in the question

Comment: The order of initialization of global objects is not generally specified; global initializers are only guaranteed to have run before the first call of a function in the translation unit.

Comment: @TankorSmash: I'm sure my answer is well-formed, but I didn't bother posting it. Please upvote me.

Comment: @KerrekSB No need to get sassy dude

Comment: @KerrekSB - Sorry, I've corrected the formatting.

Comment: @Ender Meh! [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it didn't happen. My close vote still stands.

Comment: You're really trying to ask why "things keep crashing" which isn't a good problem statement.

Comment: @Ender [You obviously don't seem to understand what MCVE means](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31125624/revisions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A unique_ptr's pointer value is null unless you initialize or assign a valid pointer value.

```
gl_vec = std::unique_ptr<std::vector<MyClass>>(new std::vector<MyClass>());
```

Comment: MyClass is the object I want to store in the vector pointed to by unique_ptr. Here I'm just trying to initialize it as MyClass is an object that I receive over the network later on.

Comment: Ok- I fixed an error in my answer. Now it assigns a pointer to a new empty vector to gl_vec.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't allocating memory for the underlying `vector`.

Instead of

```
gl_vec = std::unique_ptr<std::vector<MyClass>> ();
```

do this:

```
gl_vec = std::make_unique<std::vector<MyClass>>();
```

Or if C++14 is not available

```
gl_vec.reset(new std::vector<MyClass>());
```

Comment: Or, create the `std::vector` object when initializing the storage of the `gl_vec` variable in *glo.cpp*: `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<MyClass>> gl_vec(new std::vector<MyClass>);`

Answer (score 3):

> constexpr unique_ptr(); - Constructs a std::unique_ptr that owns nothing.

```
gl_vec = std::unique_ptr<std::vector<MyClass>> ();
```

Constructs a std::unique_ptr that owns nothing.

```
(*gl_vec).size()
```

> std::unique_ptr::operator* - operator* and operator-> provide access to the object owned by *this.

*gl_vec - provides access to nothing. Hence - crash.

What you really want to do is:

```
gl_vec = std::make_unique<std::vector<MyClass>> ();
```

Comment: I really like that, but my compiler is gcc 4.8.4 and make_unique it says is not part of std. I should give some thought to upgrading that.